# Binding Teradata Query in python not returning anything

Tags: python-3.x, connection, odbc, parameter-passing, teradata

I am trying to automate some usual db queries via python and was testing the sql parameterization

```
import teradata
import pyodbc
import sys
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="HelloWorld", version="1.0",
        logConsole=False)

session = udaExec.connect(method="odbc", system="db",
        username="username", password="password");

t = 'user_id' #dynamic column to be selected        

cursor =  session.cursor(); 


"""The below query returned only the user_id column

>>> sw_overall1
         0
0  user_id
"""
sw_overall1=cursor.execute("""select  distinct ? from 
                           table""" ,(t,)).fetchall()

sw_overall1 = DataFrame(sw_overall1)                  
cursor =  session.cursor(); 

#The below query returned the correct result                   
sw_overall2=cursor.execute("""select  distinct user_id from 
                           table""" ).fetchall()
```

Am I doing the binding incorrectly ? since without binding I get the correct output.

Comment: Column name cannot be parametrized. And using string interpolation/concatenation could lead to SQL Injection.

Comment: @lukaz , is there any way to paramterize column names then ?, if this is not a secure method what method would you suggest then ?

Comment: Parameter binding works by sending the SQL up the database without values (so all columns and tables must be know). The database then parses, optimizes, and determines the execution path (essentially compiles the sql). Then it sits there waiting for the parameters to come through. This is why tables and columns can't be parameters. Your only choice here is to concatenate the column names into your SQL, which could open you up to SQL injection. Since that's really your only choice here you'll have to insure that parameter is sanitized as well as it can be.